# How to know that the ajax last response has been reached?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to capture/know when it reached the  200(success) for the last and do something ie exit out.

How do i know that it has reached the 200 for the last time?

Here is my code below

//Main function whihc calls the save  and checkstatus function

```
   $(function () {
        $("#saveChange").click(function () {
            save().complete(function (jqXHR, responseText) {

                var stat = jqXHR.status;
                if (stat == 200) {
                    console.log("inside 200");

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        checkServerStatus().complete(function (jqXHR, responseText) {

                            if (jqXHR.status == 200) {
                                console.log("inside 200");
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    checkServerStatus().complete(function (jqXHR, responseText) {
                                        count = 0;
                                        count++;
                                        max = 10;
                                        if ((count <= max) && (jqXHR.status == 200)) {
                                            checkServerStatus();
                                            //alert(count);
                                        }

                                    });
                                    if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                        // alert(" 500 setimeout inside 500 status "+jqXHR.status + responseText);  
                                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 200) {
                                        // alert(" 200 setimeout inside 200 status "+jqXHR.status + responseText);  
                                    }
                                }, 9000);

                            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                // 500 error no submission
                                console.log("inside 500");
                                //alert(" 300 setimeout inside 500 status "+jqXHR.status + responseText);   
                                checkServerStatus();
                            } else {
                                alert("else");
                            }
                        });
                    }, 6000);
                } 

            });


        });
    });

    });
```

Comment: Look on jQuery.ajaxSetup() - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice discussion about retrying ajax requests [here](http://zeroedandnoughted.com/defensive-ajax-and-ajax-retries-in-jquery/). I would advise handling the deferreds yourself. This way you can make a dummy deferred, resolve or reject it at your whim, then chain as usual.

```
function checkServerStatus() {
    var dfd = new $.deferred();

    $.ajax({
         url : 'ajaxurl.json',
         tryCount : 0,
         retryLimit : 3,
        success : function(json) {
            dfd.resolve();
        },
        error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            if (this.tryCount++ <= this.retryLimit) {
                //try again
               $.ajax(this);
               return;
            }
            dfd.reject();
        }
    });
    return dfd;
}
```

### Chain as usual

```
checkServerStatus().then(function() {
    // success!
}, function() {
   // reached retry limit :(
});
```